# Keeping coordinates sorted

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have some coordinates (x,y) and I need these coordinates to be sorted and keep them sorted. After I sort them every coordinate change from (x,y) to (x+1,y) or (x-1,y) or (x,y-1) or (x,y+1), so the coordinates are not sorted anymore.

Is there a better way of solving this problem besides, sorting the coordinates, coordinates change, sorting the coordinates again, coordinates change, sorting the coordinates again based on the condition that every coordinate changes with +-1?

Comment: How exactly are you sorting them? That is: What is the *exact* meaning of `(x0,y0) < (x1,y1)` here? Also, a language tag and information about the data structures that you are using could help. Broadly speaking: Sorting each time would be O(nlogn) each time. But when you have, for example, a heap-like data structure, you could probably remove the coordinate, change it, and re-insert it (into its new, sorted position), or use something that is roughly based on some sort of binary search.

Comment: Let's say (x0,y0) = a, (x1,y1) = b. if(x0<x1) than a<b, if(x0==x1) we check the second coordinate if(y0<y1) than a<b. Any other case b>a. The language I'm using is C++ and I have my elements stored in a vector and I'm sorting them with the function sort from <algoriths>.

Comment: Can't edit on the second line I wanted to say "Any other case a>b"*.

Comment: So that's a simple [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) then. And I assume that you have a `vector` containing `std::pair<double,double>` or something similar. Then I think that a [`priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) or [`make_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) could be the way to go, but my C++-knowledge is a bit too rusty to just throw out some (profoundly "good") implementation example...

Comment: I understand, thank you I will look into it

Comment: Have you considered [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to make it so if (x0==x1) to compare y0 with y1 and based on y1 and y2 to sort them. Also, another problem would be that let's say the coordinates are sorted and the first one changes, and after deleting it and inserting it again in the map with the changed coordinates it gets added to the end, so while parsing the map this coordinate gets change twice instead of once (on the first position and on the last position). Not sure if I explained well.

Comment: Put them in a doubly-linked list so you don't have to delete and re-insert every time; insertion sort on nearly-sorted items takes `O(n)`. However, you have two dimensions of information, so you would have to keep two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain the sorted order when you update the coordinate by moving the coordinate to the correct place after the update.

If you are doing `(x+1, y)` or `(x, y+1)` then the coordinate will be somewhere ahead of its current position in the vector. If you are doing `(x-1, y)` or `(x, y-1)` then the coordinate will be somewhere behind of its current position in the vector.

(There is also the possibility the coordinate does not need to change position if it is still correct with respect to the other elements in the vector).

Using this, you can search ahead (or behind) for the position where the updated coordinate needs to go. As you search you can copy the elements back (or forward) to close up the gap left behind by your current element.

```
|   a   |   b   |   c   |   d   |
| {1,1} | {1,2} | {2,0} | {2,2} |
```

In the above example, consider that we update `c` to `{1,0}`. We move backwards, checking `c < b`, which is true, so we shuffle `b` forward:

```
|   a   |       |   b   |   d   |
| {1,1} |       | {1,2} | {2,2} |
```

We move back again, checking `c < a`, which is also true, so we shuffle `a` forward.

```
|       |   a   |   b   |   d   |
|       | {1,1} | {1,2} | {2,2} |
```

At this point we have reached the beginning of the vector so we know that `c` must go in this position.

```
|   c   |   a   |   b   |   d   |
| {1,0} | {1,1} | {1,2} | {2,2} |
```

The other terminal case is when `c` is no longer less than the element you are checking.

This works similarly in the forwards direction.

Some code to demonstrate this idea:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;

    void Adjust(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0: x++; return;
            case 1: y++; return;
            case 2: x--; return;
            case 3: y--; return;
        }
    }

    bool operator<(const Point & rhs) {
        if (x == rhs.x)
            return y < rhs.y;

        return x < rhs.x;
    }

    bool operator>(const Point & rhs) {
        if (x == rhs.x)
            return y > rhs.y;

        return x > rhs.x;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Point> points;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            points.push_back({i,j});
    }

    std::sort(std::begin(points), std::end(points));

    std::default_random_engine rng{std::time(nullptr)};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distrib{0, 3};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        for (auto iter = std::begin(points); iter != std::end(points); ++iter) {
            auto p = *iter;
            int adjustment = distrib(rng);

            p.Adjust(adjustment);

            auto current = iter;

            if (adjustment < 2) {
                auto next = std::next(current);

                while (next != std::end(points) && p > *next) {
                    *current = *next;
                    current = next;
                    next = std::next(current);
                }

                *current = p;
            }
            else if (current != std::begin(points)) {
                auto prev = std::prev(current);

                while (p < *prev) {
                    *current = *prev;
                    current = prev;

                    if (current != std::begin(points))
                        prev = std::prev(current);
                    else
                        break;
                }

                *current = p;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto && p : points)
        std::cout << "{" << p.x << "," << p.y << "}\n";

    std::cout << "is_sorted = "
        << std::is_sorted(std::begin(points), std::end(points))
        << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://www.ideone.com/ZcAVbF)

*Disclaimer: I haven't measured the performance of this solution. It may be slower than just sorting the vector after all the updates due to the shuffling that happens for every element update.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood what you want to say if the coordinates change only by +-1 the new coordinate will be close to the current coordinate so we can just put it to the right position with only moving a few elements. I thought about that but the problem with this is that all coordinates need to change once before you start changing them again. What I mean is that if you change a coordinate and move it forward to a new position, when you get to that position again you can't change that coordinate until all the other coordinates changed.

Answer (score 1):

A [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) will handle all this for you.  In particular, the contents are inherently sorted by the set members' `operator<` function, so when you insert new items you don't have to do any sorting yourself.  The complexity of an insertion is O(log(N)).

As for sorting the coordinates correctly, you can make use of the fact that `std::pair` defines [`operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) like so:

```
If lhs.first<rhs.first, returns true. Otherwise, if rhs.first<lhs.first, returns false. Otherwise, if lhs.second<rhs.second, returns true. Otherwise, returns false.
```

which is what you say you want.

So, to sum up, you can do:

```
#include <utility>
#include <set>

using coordinate = std::pair<int, int>;
std::set<coordinate> stored_coordinates;
```

where the first member of the `std::pair` representing a `coordinate` is `x` and the second is `y`.

Finally, if you want to associate a data item with each coordinate, use a `map` instead, with a `std::pair` as the key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I really didn't know that the ```operator<``` for the ```std::pair``` is implemented like this, it's a really useful thing to know. Also, yes this could be an alternative but I don't think the time will be better than sorting the array after the coordinates change, because if you have n coordinates and you do n insertions the complexity will be O(N*log(N))... Also, you will need two sets so when you change a coordinate to insert the new coordinate in the second set. After all elements changed you just copy the second set to the first set and do it again.